# What's the difference between layer.position.y and layer.frame.origin.y?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

It seems like one points directly to the layer, and the other to the frame, but how are they functionally different? They both determine the position of the same view...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin of the frame is the upper left corner of the frame while the position is (as long as you don't change the anchor point) the center of the frame.